# Jquery Datepicker not working in a control

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to use a simple datepicker in a control. When the user clicks on the textbox, the calendar should be displayed. But, the calendar isn't popping up.

Here is my code.

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Activity.ascx.cs" Inherits="Website.Controls.Activity"  %>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%= DateHtmlInputText.ClientID %>').datepicker();
    });
    </script>

    <div id="activity">
       <asp:TextBox ID="DateHtmlInputText" CssClass="datePicker" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

Comment: View the source of the page when viewed from the browser. what's the id that is printed inside the jquery selector? is it the same id the textbox has?

Comment: Yes, it is. The javascript is loading properly too and there are no JS errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at jQuery UI Date Picker, they have working examples that you can use/apply.  Make sure that you include all the dependencies if you don't use the complete UI library.  You can use the "view source" link below the example to see the HTML/JavaScript of how the example was made.

[jQuery UI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

**Example with .NET TextBox Control**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Zachary. I had downloaded the library from Jquery website. I am using it a user control. Am I missing something? I checked other posts too, and they all mentioned to use ClientID of the control, which is pretty much I was doing before too.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it's using jQuery UI, the latest version is 1.8.14.  You might try going [here](http://jqueryui.com/download) and downloading it again.  Don't forget, you'll need to include a theme for jQuery UI so the popup is styled properly.  You code for getting the ID looks right, but you have a capital "P" in "datePicker", should be all lower case for jQuery UI.

Comment: I have used this library too: <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js">, but that doesn't seem to work either. "datePicker" is a class name. Does it matter? I am not using it here anyways. I understand the styling aspect, I will work on it once the datepicker will work :(

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, when you bind the date picker the syntax should be "$( "#<%= DateHtmlInputText.ClientID %>" ).datepicker();".  Notice that "datepicker()" is all lower case, you example above has it in upper case.  This would cause it not to bind.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the input. I have updated it, but it is STILL nor working!! Argh....I am using it in a user control...

Comment: It doesn't matte that your using it in a User Control, I do this all the time with the various jQuery UI elements.  When troubleshooting things like this, you should use Firebug for Firefox.  You can trace everything that is happening and edit/run JavaScript real-time on your page.  You might see a simple mistake/typo that is causing your problem.

Comment: Much appreciate your help. I am using firebug and I don't see any JS errors. I have used other libraries successfully, just not this one. It must be a silly mistake, but in these 6 lines I can't figure out the problem and thought fresh eyes might notice something that I am not.

Comment: Thanks for the code, Zachary. I tried your code and even that didn't work!

Comment: I finally managed to get a JS error: Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Cannot modify properties of a WrappedNative"  nsresult: "0x80570034 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CANT_MODIFY_PROP_ON_WN)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://global/content/bindings/autocomplete.xml :: onxblpopuphiding :: line 848"  data: no]

Comment: The code I posted works, I used in a User Control that I added to a page.  Maybe your having a conflict with something else (like double loading jQuery).  Try building a simple HTML page to see if you can get it to work in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you include proper JavaScript references in your page/masterpage and also ensure of you are using updatepanel in your control markup then you should include the following JavaScript end request handler in your page

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("#txttdate").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });

                $('.timepicker_input').timepicker({
                    showPeriod: true,
                    showLeadingZero: true
                });
  });
```

**EDIT**

If you are not using updatepanel then you should also enclose the datpicker() call in

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
}
```

it will make sure that your function will execute only after complete load

also visit [Jquery Datepicker UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) as suggested by our peer for more insights

Hope it may help you

Comment: I am not using updatepanel. Even the 6 lines code that I mentioned in this post is not working. The libraries need to be referenced in the page and not the control?

Comment: Thanks Devjosh, it is still not working. This the code I am trying to implement <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%= DateHtmlInputText.ClientID %>').datePicker();
        });

</script>